# how to ping the ip of linux running under vmware from window(host) of that same PC

Tags: linux, vmware

I have window 7, and install Enterprises LINUX in vmware workstation, I have assign static IP I  eth0 and eth1, and both are pinging from root as well as oracle user, but I cannot able to ping either of them from window of that same machine. Please help to advise how can i ping those static IP from my window 7 which is a host.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your VMWare networking setup for that virtual machine.
If the virtual machine is connected via a [bridge](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_bridged.html) or via a [host-only](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_hostonly.html) network, you can just ping the VM's address.

If you're using [NAT](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_nat.html), then it's a problem since the VM has a private IP that's not seen by the host. The opposite ping should however work (if VMWare's NAT is smart enough) - you should be able to ping the host from the VM.